# No me esta mostrando los valores en mi datatables jquery

Tags: laravel, oracle

El problema que tengo es ala hora de mostrar mis datos en mi datatables de jquery que instale en laravel por que realizo la consulta en el controlador y si me esta traendo todos los datos de esa tabla el problema es ala hora de pasarla ala vista que realizo el foreach solo me muestra el numero de los datos que hay pero no los datos que coloco nose si es por que son demaciados datos o cual puede ser el problema

**Este es mi controlador donde realizo la consulta para que me traiga todos los datos de mi base de mi tabla y ahi los mando para la vista formulario**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\importar;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class vista extends Controller
{
    public function vista_inicio()
    {
        $datos = importar::all();


        return \View::make('formulario')->with(
            [
            'datos' => $datos
        ]
        );
    }
}
```

**Esta es mi vista mi datatables donde recorro la variable datos pero en este punto me esta traendo en blando los datos no me muestra la informacion**

```
          <br>
    <br>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
            <th>ID_ENLACE</th>
            <th>FECHA_FACTURA</th>
            <th>FECHA_INGRESO</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($datos as $dato)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$dato->PROVEEDOR}}</td>
                <td>{{$dato->ID_ENLACE}}</td>
                <td>{{$dato->FECHA_FACTURA}}</td>
                <td>{{$dato->FECHA_INGRESO}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

este es mi datatables donde muestra los datos pero solo me esta mostrando cuantos datos hay pero no la informacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el vardump que realizo en el controlador de $datos y efectivamente me esta traendo los datos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que el problema pudiera ser que tienes el `<tbody>` dentro del `foreach`

Comment: al parecer tampoco sigue con el mismo problema probe y nada

Comment: Coloca el <tbody> antes del foreach y el final del foreach antes del cierre del </tbody>  espero con eso se te solucione

Comment: si eso acabo de realizarlo pero me sigue igual ahi modifique el codigo para que observen

Comment: Entonces tienes un problema con el recorrido del foreach y la asignación de los valores, yo no uso laravel, ya te habia puesto una respuesta pero no cargo correctamente y la borre, y ahi se quedo no puedo añadir otra respuesta.

Comment: Aunque tengo una duda por que estoy trabajando con una base de oracle y no de mysql no se si ese puede ser algun problema que el datatables solo sea para mysql

Comment: Podrías publicar el código donde creas el datatables

Comment: o lo resolvi el problema es que las tengo en mayusculas y tienen que ser en minusculas las asignaciones

Answer (score 0):

las asignaciones en el forach tienen que estar en minusculas y no en mayusculas

```
      <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
                <th>ID_ENLACE</th>
                <th>FECHA_FACTURA</th>
                <th>FECHA_INGRESO</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($datos as $datos)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$datos->proveedor}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datos->id_enlace}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datos->fecha_factura}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datos->fecha_ingreso}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```